# What happened to the Jango Fett template?

Tags: star-wars, clones

During the clone rebellion on Kamino, the 501st secured Jango Fett's DNA template before finishing off the remaining renegade clones. That was about a decade before the rebellion's attack. So are there any sources regarding how long the Empire or its successors continued to use cloned Stormtroopers, and more specifically how long did they continue to use Jango Fett's template? Did the Empire or its successors eventually lose/destroyed it, or do they still possess it?

Comment: I've heard rumours (possibly based on the screening of the *Rebels* season 2 premiere in Anaheim last month) that the clone troopers were retired pretty quickly after the Clone Wars. We'll more than likely learn more in season 2 of *Rebels*

Comment: I don't know if we have an answer to the last question (does the Empire still possess the DNA template?), but [my answer to another question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/72401/31936) sums up what we know about how long they continued to use Fett's clones (to the best of my knowledge it's still up to date).

Comment: I believe there's some discussion on it in some of the Legends.  They began phasing out clones after the clone wars slowly as the empire moved to using non-clone troops.  By the end, many of the clones have been replaced.  I think I read something about this in Alligance

Comment: Weren't the Kamino's purged after their involvement in the renegade cloning attempt?  With the loss of Kamino expertise the Empire would be limited to less effective cloning techniques (Spaarti produce worse troops).

Comment: @TysonoftheNorthwest To hide the rebellion before its maturity, all rebel clones were created and trained in a single city while the rest of the planet continue the facade of serving the Empire. The Clone Masters were titles given to the technical heads of the rebel effort. When the rebellion was put down, only the rebel city was destroyed and surviving Clone Masters were pressed back into Imperial service. So I would say Kaminoan cloning expertise didn't suffer major setbacks, only a major loss of trust from the Emperor.

Comment: @TysonoftheNorthwest I'd like to add that Spaarti cloning isn't necessarily inferior. Besides the risk of clone madness, the quality of successful clones depend on the memory flashes used. Palpatine's Spaarti clones were only flashed with the most basic of training so they were definitely inferior to newly graduated and veteran Kaminoan clones alike. The cloning of Galen Marek, however, shows that advanced flashing of training, and entire memories and experiences is possible. When successful, such a clone trooper can be equal to any veteran and ready in a year.

Comment: @thegratjedi Totally, but the that individual clone was one in a long line of failures.  Also, it looks like (from wookieepedia) that the Galen clone was a Kamino clone not Spaarti.  Either way whatever method was used was more complex, failure prone, and costly than the methods used on clone troopers (but then again cloning Jedi is always far more problematic).

Comment: Is there any way I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 4):

*Star Wars: The Clone Wars* implied that the template wouldn't last infinitely.

From the episode *Clone Cadets*:

> Ever since the unfortunate death of Jango Fett, we have had to stretch his DNA to produce more clones...
>
> ...Sometimes our efforts are less than successful.

*Star Wars: Rebels* shows that the Empire no longer uses the clone troopers.

Without being explicably told what happened, we can probably assume that the template was corrupted beyond use and/or the Empire decided to retire it along with the clone program.